# Spring MVC: Can not deserialize instance of out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have been beating my head against this for a while now and still no joy. I am new to Spring and could really use some help.

I am trying to use Spring Boot to return a list of codes from a DB table. When I call my REST controller from a URL in a browser...

**Example URL:** localhost:8081/cis/utl/lookupchoice/O.s/

It returns this:

```
[
{"lookupId":10,"choiceGroup":"O.s","choiceCode":null,"displayLabel":"Pending","hidden":false,"displayOrder":1},
{"lookupId":11,"choiceGroup":"O.s","choiceCode":null,"displayLabel":"Active","hidden":false,"displayOrder":2},
{"lookupId":12,"choiceGroup":"O.s","choiceCode":null,"displayLabel":"Archived","hidden":false,"displayOrder":3},
{"lookupId":13,"choiceGroup":"O.s","choiceCode":null,"displayLabel":"Placeholder","hidden":false,"displayOrder":4}
]
```

But, I get an error message when trying to run this from a client controller. The call looks like this:

```
//
//Compiles but does not work
LookupChoice lookupChoice = restTemplate.getForObject(REST_URI+"/utl/lookupchoice/O.s/",
         LookupChoice.class);
```

**The error:** *nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.MyPakage.repository.LookupChoice out of START_ARRAY token*

Assuming the error occurs because an array is returned instead of a single object, I changed the code to this:

```
//
//Does not compile
Iterable<LookupChoice> lookupChoice = restTemplate.getForObject(REST_URI+"/utl/lookupchoice/U.r/",
         Iterable<LookupChoice.class>);
```

But,  now I get an error in Intellij. It's indicating that an "**Expression expected**" for the ***Iterable***<***LookupChoice.class>*** param, and I can't get past this.

Thank you for your time and assistance,
Ed

Thanks for your reply. I opted for this and it all seems to work now. Thanks for your help!

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity;
Object[] lookupChoice;

responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(REST_SERVICE_URI+"/utl/lookupchoice/O.s/" , Object[].class);
lookupChoice = responseEntity.getBody();
model.addAttribute("Status", lookupChoice);
```

Comment: About the above, are there any tweaks that would make this more elegant, and/or improve performance etc?

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't compile is because it's impossible in Java to pass a class of generic type parameters because they don't exist at runtime.

You have two options here, either use an array (`LookupChoice[]`) and convert it to a `List<LookupChoice>` if necessary:

```
restTemplate.getForObject(url, LookupChoice[]);
```

Or you can use the `ParameterizedTypeReference`:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<LookupChoice>>() {}).getBody()
```

It is an interface though, so either subclass it or use an anonymous class like I did in the code example above.

Also, `ParameterizedTypeReference` only works on the `exchange()` method if I'm not mistaken, so you'll get a `ResponseEntity` in stead of your raw object, so you'll have to use the `getBody()` method.